# QGIS and PYQT5: Getting QgsAttributeForm.modeChanged signal

Tags: qgis-3, pyqt5

I wonder how I can catch the signal, that attributes in a form are editable?

E.G. I open a form to see the values of the attributes of my geodata. Then I click on the "pencil" in QGIS (to make data editable). And right now a message should occure.

I tried:

```
def test(): qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Status: ", u"Status: ")

    myDialog.modeChanged.connect(test)
```

...but that`s obviously not the correct way. Could anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution now.
Via the layerObject it`s possible to get the EditingStatus:

```
   def testAusgabe(): qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Statusx: ", u"Statusy: ")

    MyLayer.editCommandStarted.connect(testAusgabe)
    MyLayer.editingStarted.connect(testAusgabe)
```